# C# Regex not matching Regex101

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which I'm trying to match with Regex in C#.

The string is `Hello1004,"7"`.

I'm creating the Regex with

```
var reg = new Regex(@"hello\s*\[?\s*,?\s*(?<group1>\d+)\s*,\s*""(?<group2>[^""]+)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

(There may be multiple spaces, a `[` or a `,` before `1004`.)

`1004` may not always be `1004`, but it will always be a 4-digit number.

What I'm trying to get is:

- group1: `1004`
- group2: `7`

You can see a Regex101 demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/y02qoD/2).

It works perfectly in the demo, but when doing

```
foreach (var match in reg.Matches(text))
{
    var group1 = match.Groups["group1"]?.Value;
    var group2 = match.Groups["group2"]?.Value;
}
```

`group1` is empty and `group2` has `1004` in it. If I put a space between `Hello` and `1004` it works fine in C#.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this discrepancy between the two?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, .Net Framework 4.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/FA8WNg, it seems working.

Comment: Same here. Did a test in LinqPad:
var s = @"Hello1004,""7"""; 
 var reg = new Regex(@"hello\s*\[?\s*,?\s*(?<group1>\d+)\s*,\s*""(?<group2>[^""]+)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
 reg.Match(s).Dump();

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmmm... That does seem to work. However, it's definitely not working in my real-world application. I'll update the question with my version of .NET in case that applies.

Comment: I think only your *real* input is of interest.

Comment: Post a minimal *complete* verifiable example of your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one problem is that in the foreach function, C# is not determining the return type of `foreach( var match in reg.Matches(text) )` to create a variant from.

I get this error in C# VS2015
`Program.cs(48,24,48,30): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Groups' and no extension method 'Groups' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

But, if changed to explicit typing `Match` it compiles and run's like it's
supposed to.

```
        var text = @"Hello1004,""7""";
        var reg = new Regex(@"hello\s*\[?\s*,?\s*(?<group1>\d+)\s*,\s*""(?<group2>[^""]+)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(text))
        {
            var group1 = match.Groups["group1"]?.Value;
            var group2 = match.Groups["group2"]?.Value;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", group1, group2);
        }
```

Output

```
1004 , 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is that you are being TOO specific. The first thing you want to do is match 4 digit, and than match the contents of "...". So you just need to only say that. Don't match things you don't need to unless you are using them as anchors or validation.

```
(?<group1>\d{4})[^"]*"(?<group2>[^"]*)
```